# Преобразование из json в объект Java

Tags: java, json, gson

Есть `json` файл. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как преобразовать в объект с помощью `gson`

```
{
  "movie": [
    {
      "name": "Home alone",
      "year": 1995,
      "description": "Comedy",
      "director": {
        "fullName": "Testov Test"
      },
      "cast": [
        {
          "fullName": "Testov Test",
          "role": "some role"
        },
        {
          "fullName": "Testov Test",
          "role": "some role"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "the ring",
      "year": 1990,
      "description": "horor",
      "director": {
        "fullName": "Some Director"
      },
      "cast": [
        {
          "fullName": "some actor",
          "role": "some role"
        },
        {
          "fullName": "Some Girl",
          "role": "some role"
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

Класс:

```
public class Movie{
    private String name;
    private int year;
    private String description;
    // какое должно быть поле для director ?
    // какое должно быть поле cast ?
}
```

Comment: Для полей `director` и `cast` Вам нужно создать классы и в них поля, согласно Вашего `json`-а

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В таких случаях идете на этот прекрасный ресурс: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/
Создаете себе POJO для ваших классов :

```
public class Cast {

@SerializedName("fullName")
@Expose
private String fullName;
@SerializedName("role")
@Expose
private String role;

public String getFullName() {
return fullName;
}

public void setFullName(String fullName) {
this.fullName = fullName;
}

public String getRole() {
return role;
}

public void setRole(String role) {
this.role = role;
}

}

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Director {

@SerializedName("fullName")
@Expose
private String fullName;

public String getFullName() {
return fullName;
}

public void setFullName(String fullName) {
this.fullName = fullName;
}

}


package com.example;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Movie {

@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;@SerializedName("year")
@Expose
private Integer year;
@SerializedName("description")
@Expose
private String description;
@SerializedName("director")
@Expose
private Director director;
@SerializedName("cast")
@Expose
private List<Cast> cast = null;

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public Integer getYear() {
return year;
}

public void setYear(Integer year) {
this.year = year;
}

public String getDescription() {
return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
this.description = description;
}

public Director getDirector() {
return director;
}

public void setDirector(Director director) {
this.director = director;
}

public List<Cast> getCast() {
return cast;
}

public void setCast(List<Cast> cast) {
this.cast = cast;
}

}

 package com.example;

 import java.util.List;
 import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
 import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

 public class Response {

 @SerializedName("movie")
 @Expose
 private List<Movie> movie = null;

 public List<Movie> getMovie() {
 return movie;
 }

 public void setMovie(List<Movie> movie) {
 this.movie = movie;
 }
```

Ну и потом все просто (надеюсь у Вас добавлены все необходимые зависимости добавляющие Gson в Ваш проект)

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Response response = gson.fromJson(yourJson, Response.class);
List<Movie> movies = response.getMovie();
```